# Rpi 2 Model B connected via ethernet, ssh works, either 'Destination Host Unreachable' or 'Temporary failure in name resolution' when pinging

Tags: raspbian, ethernet, internet

I have a raspberry pi setup with Raspbian installed. I was able to ssh into the pi via my windows 10 pc. It became immediately apparent that something was off when I tried to run

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.raspberrypi.org'
Err:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/buster/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.raspberrypi.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I then attempted to ping my pc from the pi and got

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping 192.168.68.127
PING 192.168.68.127 (192.168.68.127) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.163 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.163 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.163 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I pinged google.com

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

and got a different error. Here is the ifconfig and route -n

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.163  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::e6e2:2846:5d89:87da  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:30:01:91  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 25734  bytes 3823814 (3.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 124  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19327  bytes 4070359 (3.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1136  bytes 110021 (107.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1136  bytes 110021 (107.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

does anyone know what is causing these issues?

Comment: It is unclear  what is connected to what. You are attempting to ping something on a different network.

Comment: It's a DNS failure - apart from that, your pi is on 192.168.1.0/24 subnet, and you're trying to ping 192.168.68.127 ... a different subnet ... is your pi connected to a router that routes between those two subnets?

Comment: It's a routing failure. 192.168.68.127/24 isn't in the same subnet as 192.168.1.163/24 so how can the kernel route packets to a network that isn't part of your lan and doesn't have an explicit route?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My /etc/resolv.conf file only had 127.0.0.1 as the dns, after adding 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1 I was able to upgrade.

If you are using dhcp then in order to update the file you need to change the dhcpd file:

`sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf`

add this to the bottom of the file to add the cloudflare dns servers:

`static domain_name_servers=1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1`

or alternatively the google domain servers

`static domain_name_servers=8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8`

then just restart the dhcp service and you should be good to proceed with your upgrades:

`sudo service dhcpcd restart`